# Integer representation in another basis where division is also easy?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, divisibility

I need a way to represent numbers in a smaller basis (say 16-bit words) where I can do division in an easy way, without floating point.

The Chinnese Remainer Theorem is one representation and it  allows us to represent numbers in terms of a basis of co-prime integers. Take the basis $(3,5,7)$, then the representation of $4$ and $7$ in that basis is

$$4 = (4 \mbox{ mod } 3, 4 \mbox{ mod } 5, 4 \mbox{ mod } 7) = (1, 4, 4)\\7 = (7 \mbox{ mod } 3, 7 \mbox{ mod } 5, 7 \mbox{ mod } 7) = (1, 2, 0)$$

Then, $4+7$ is just the sum coefficient-wise:

$$4 + 7 = (1+1 \mbox{ mod } 3, 2+4 \mbox{ mod } 5, 4+0 \mbox{ mod } 7) = (2, 1, 4)$$

Then, $4.7$ is just the product coefficient-wise:

$$4.7 = (1.1 \mbox{ mod } 3, 2.4 \mbox{ mod } 5, 4.0 \mbox{ mod } 7) = (1, 3, 0)$$

However, division is hard. What are good algorithms for integer division (with round interger as output) that do not require floating point?

Can you think of another basis representation where sum, product, subtraciton is easy and division is a little bit easy? I cannot do any floating point.  Due do the basis size being 16-bit, this also fit the modular artihmetic tag, but I'm not sure if I can choose the modular maximum size.

**update**: this is needed in the context of Fully Homomorphic Encryption, where we can only multiply coefficient-wise and add coefficient-wise polynomials, and the polynomial coefficients are modulo some big number like 1 million

Comment: Does "division" mean modular division $\,a/b = ab^{-1} \pmod{m}\,$ or are you trying to use modular arithmetic to compute integer division with remainder $\,a = qb + r,\ 0\le r < b?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque it's regular integer division with remainder but we ignore the remainder (but if possible would be nice to have the remainder)